# Looking for a more elegant way of solving this sql query

Tags: sql

I was handed a scenario that had the schema of

Product:

```
maker   model   type
A   1232    PC
A   1233    PC
A   1276    Printer
A   1298    Laptop
A   1401    Printer
A   1408    Printer
A   1752    Laptop
B   1121    PC
B   1750    Laptop
C   1321    Laptop
D   1288    Printer
D   1433    Printer
E   1260    PC
E   1434    Printer
E   2112    PC
E   2113    PC
```

And the query was to

> Get the makers who produce only one product type and more than one
>   model.
>
> Output columns should have been maker and type.

And this is what I came up with.

```
select distinct maker, type
from Product
where maker in (select maker
                from Product
                group by maker, type
                having count(model) > 1
                except
                select maker
                from 
                (
                    select distinct maker, type
                    from Product
                ) A
                group by maker
                having count(type) > 1)
```

I know this doesn't seem elegant in any way, so I was wondering whether someone could come up with a better alternative and explain as to why is it better than the query stated above.

---

EDIT: Please make sure that the answer is just two columns wide which is

Maker, Type

Comment: Can you please add a tag for your RDBMS engine?

Comment: The sub-query can simply be a GROUP BY, with conditions in HAVING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select distinct p.maker, p.type
from product p
where exists (select 1
              from product p2
              where p2.maker = p.maker and p2.type = p.type and p2.model <> p.model
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from product p2
                  where p2.maker = p.maker and p2.type <> p.type
                 );
```

Another version uses explicit aggregation:

```
select p.maker, p.type
from product p
where not exists (select 1
                  from product p2
                  where p2.maker = p.maker and p2.type <> p.type
                 )
group by p.maker, p.type
having min(model) <> max(model);
```

And, for completeness, here is a version that only uses window functions:

```
select p.model, p.type
from (select p.*,
             min(type) over (partition by maker) as mintype,
             max(type) over (partition by maker) as maxtype,
             row_number() over (partition by maker, type order by model) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by maker, type) as cnt
      from product p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1 and
      mintype = maxtype and
      cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT maker, MIN(type) as type
FROM Product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT model) > 1;
```

Comment: In most databases, this will return an error (`type` is not begin aggregated).  In MySQL, it will only return one `type` per maker.

Comment: I know, but the question is which maker makes one type, so I thought it wold be okay

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct model) as unique_model_count,
       count(distinct type) as unique_type_count,
       maker
from Product
group by maker
having unique_type_count=1 and unique_model_count>1
```

Comment: _Definitely_ the "right" answer to this one!  However, I think that both "maker" and "type" need to be included; an easy fix to what's shown here.  (Having not tried it ...) I am not 100%-sure that column-names can be used as shown in the "having" clause, but maybe that the "count()" expressions must be repeated here . . .?

Comment: Correct logic, but may throw an error if the RDBMS, which was not specified, does not allow aliases in the having clause.

Comment: @MikeRobinson . . . I would argue that this is *not* the right answer, because it does not include `type`.